# Which symbols can be used in `openssl passwd -crypt`?

Tags: bash, openssl, command-line-interface

I am writing a bash script to create user logins. Everything is fine apart from the password encryption. My code is something like this:

```
MYPASS="randomString"
CRYPTPASS="$(openssl passwd -crypt $MYPASS)"
sudo usermod -p $CRYPTPASS newUsername
```

I've just had problems with a password that contained `$`, `!` and `#`. I'm assuming the problem was with the encryption in the `openssl` command.  I'm not sure which symbol(s) were causing the problem but the only way it would work for this particular login was to remove all the symbols. However, in a different password, the `+` symbol worked fine.

I'd like to use as many symbols as possible. Which characters should be avoided in `openssl passwd -crypt`? What is the problem with this method? Are there other methods of encryption where more symbols could be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote variable expansions so the shell doesn't trip up on special characters.

```
CRYPTPASS="$(openssl passwd -crypt "$MYPASS")"
sudo usermod -p "$CRYPTPASS" newUsername
```

The outer quotes aren't strictly necessary. Remove them if you like.

```
CRYPTPASS=$(openssl passwd -crypt "$MYPASS")
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. It felt like a string containing `!` needed the double quotes when declaring the variable, but maybe putting the quotes in the statement, as you suggest, would solve that problem.